# Why does netCDF4 give different results depending on how data is read?

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

I am coding in python, and trying to use netCDF4 to read in some floating point netCDF data.  Mt original code looked like

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

infile='blahblahblah'

ds = Dataset(infile)
start_pt = 5   # or whatever
x = ds.variables['thedata'][start_pt:start_pt+2,:,:,:]
```

Now, because of various and sundry other things, I now have to read 'thedata' one slice at a time:

```
x = np.zeros([2,I,J,K])   # I,J,K match size of input array
for n in range(2):
    x[n,:,:,:] = ds.variables['thedata'][start_pt+n,:,:,:]
```

The thing is that the two methods of reading give slightly different results.  Nothing big, like one part in 10 to the fifth, but still ....

So can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can guarantee the same results from the two methods?  My thought was that the first method perhaps automatically establishes x as being the same type as the input data, while the second method establishes x as the default type for a numpy array.  However, the input data is 64 bit and I thought the default for a numpy array was also 64 bit.  So that doesn't explain it.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the type of each (with type(...))?

Answer (score 0):

The first example pulls the data into a NetCDF4 Variable object, while the second example pulls the data into a numpy array. Is it possible that the Variable object is just displaying the data with a different amount of precision?